# Should a privileged port (<1024) be used to deploy Postgresql in production?

Tags: postgresql, linux

I've never found a recommendation to run Postgresql on a privileged port in production. What type of port should be used in production regarding security and best practices?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Linux. Sorry for leaving that out.

Comment: Why would you want to run Postgresql on a privileged port? Why run on any port other then the default? Changing ports is merely security through obscurity anyway.

Comment: @Colin'tHart If  I use a non-privilege port, won't any executable be able to take over the port and listen in on the traffic?  Granted, this is general advice I have read and not specific to PG deployments.

Comment: @Colin'tHart Correction on my part: I was worried about `server spoofing`. Not about external attacks. Turns out the PG manual already discusses how to prevent server spoofing: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/preventing-server-spoofing.html

Comment: In production, PostgreSQL will typically be on its own box alone without user accounts or on a box where user accounts are considered to be safe, that is not knowingly attacking things by trying to start processes that bind on important ports. Also PostgreSQL should be configured to start on boot before many other things, which reduce the window opportunity to grab its TCP/IP port.

Comment: If postgres starts first no other application can claim port 5432 or listen to the traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running PostgreSQL under 1024 requires some hacking. It's almost impossible outside of win32. From the [`backend/main/main.c`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/9d4649ca49416111aee2c84b7e4441a0b7aa2fac/src/backend/main/main.c#L389),

> "root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted. The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent possible system security compromise.  See the documentation for more information on how to properly start the server.

After which the backend calls `exit(1)`. It also doesn't run as a `setuid` script. From the [source](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/9d4649ca49416111aee2c84b7e4441a0b7aa2fac/src/backend/main/main.c#L389),

> Also make sure that real and effective uids are the same. Executing as a setuid program from a root shell is a security hole, since on many platforms a nefarious subroutine could setuid back to root if real uid is root.  (Since nobody actually uses postgres as a setuid program, trying to actively fix this situation seems more trouble than it's worth; we'll just expend the effort to check for it.)

The only way to even set this up on Linux that I know of is

- IPTABLES
- Reverse Proxy
- Recompile the kernel
- `setcap` with [`cap_net_bind_service` capability](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) (never tried it)

However, if you are worried about server spoofing (another server taking over the non-privilege connection before the PG executable) you can still be secure if you take some pre-cautions, as explained in [Preventing Server Spoofing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/preventing-server-spoofing.html):

- Local connection: use a Unix domain socket directory (unix_socket_directories) that has write permission only for a trusted local user.
- Local connection: use `requirepeer` to specify the required owner of the server process connected to the socket.
- TCP connection: the best solution is to use SSL certificates and make sure that clients check the server's certificate.

Comment: What about using setcap with CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE on the executable? Or would that lead to just another security hole?

Comment: SSH port-forwarding is the simple and secure way to bind any service to any desired port not already used.

Comment: @da99 I actually think that may work I'll update my post.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @da99 yea, if your goal is simply to prevent server spoofing **use ssl** and just turn off UDP.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Is UDP used just for PG statistics? Should I ask a separate question about this? I seem to be having trouble finding it in the PG manual.

Comment: erg, turn off connections from Unix domain socket. Not UDP, typo.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Should  Kondybas's comment (ie use SSH port-forwarding) be included too?

Comment: @da99 I'm cool with that, it's just a reverse proxy though =) Yes. SSH can do it, and it's a pretty reasonable method of doing it. You would have to run SSH as root though, or use `capabilities` or something.

Answer (score 2):

Using a privileged port for Postgres would require the postgres daemon to run with root privileges, which in itself is a security vulnerability. So, no, you should **not** use a privileged port for Postgres.

Comment: "to run with root privileges" or be just given the appropriate capability to bind to low numbered ports. No need for full root rights to do that on any modern Unix system. See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/414258/6368697